# Parse Chordpro in React native

Tags: android, parsing, react-native, chord

I want to edit chordpro files in my app. The problem is: **How to display chords (exactly!)over the lyrics**. 
I have tried to position the chords with `position: absolute`. But it did not really work in React Native. Of course I could work with HTML Syntax (react-native-htmlview). But I think it's not the most elegant solution. 
Maybe someone has an approach for a solution?

*ChordPro syntax.*

```
{title: Swing Low Sweet Chariot}

[Chorus]
Swing [D]low, sweet [G]chari[D]ot,
Comin’ for to carry me [A7]home.
```

*Output*

```
      D          G    D
Swing low, sweet chariot,
                       A7
Comin’ for to carry me home.
```

Comment: Did you find a solution on this, I would like to do it on React  not native..